# Array folding into a single element

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers, data-structures

This is an interview question not a homework.

Given a array of 1 to 2 ^N. For eg: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 (2^3) .Imagine this array is written on a paper, we need to fold this into half, so that the left half will be mirrored and then moved underneath the right half like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 left  |  right
 half  |  half
```

becomes

```
5 6 7 8
4 3 2 1
```

And the next fold we take the *right* half instead, mirroring it and moving it below the left half,

```
 5 6 
 4 3 
 8 7
 1 2
```

The paper has to be folded, changing direction (left-vs-right) each time, until we have all the elements in the single column like this

```
 6
 3
 7 
 2
 5
 4
 8 
 1
```

My solution, 
First step :
Create a linked list for the second half of the original array, and reverse the first half and connect it with head pointers,

```
5 6 7 8 
| | | |
4 3 2 1
```

And store the head pointers of linked list in an array called headarray

Iteratively :

fold the head array, for each fold either the first half and second half headers will be linked. Delete the head pointers from the headarray once it is linked.

Continue until w have a single head pointer in the head array.

But the interviewer asked me to solve it in stack. Could anyone help in getting this solved in stack and also point out if have done any mistake in my solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the first step you move the second half at the beginning, and reverse the first. In the second step the first half (5, 6) is kept in place instead of pushing in front the second half. On third iteration the second half (6) is moved in front again.

Comment: What does stack mean in this case? Is it push/pop structure, or CPU stack (no dynamic allocations)?

Comment: push/pop structure most probably

Comment: You say to imagine the array is written on paper, but if you fold a piece of paper, you don't get that order on the second fold. The 1 would be above the 8 and the 2 would be above the 7. Did you garble the problem?

Comment: @DouglasZare, I've edited it to try to explain it more clearly. I reasonably sure I have understand the original intent of the OP. At each iteration, the direction (left-vs-right) changes, this is something I didn't notice at first, but it was in the original text.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by using a stack and the original array. I will not code the solution for you, but I will point out how to solve it.

1. push the array elements on to the stack following the rules we'll discuss further down
2. right after that pop the stack back into the array starting at index 0
3. repeat until the end condition is fulfilled

Rule for filling the stack:

- initially consider your array as one 'segment'
- divide the segment in half; the first half you will iterate in reverse order(right->left), the second one in natural order (left->right)
- You start pushing on to the stack from the end of the array:

  - if the iteration is Odd, push the odd half(s) first,
  - if the iteration is even start with the even half(s) first
- repeat, and keep half-ing your segments until they contain only one element; this is your stop condition

This is a little abstract, so let's consider your example:

iter=1    `->1234` `<-5678`  Arrows show the direction of iteration

start from the end and fill the stack; inter is odd so start with the first odd half encountered

```
5
6
7
8
4  <-notice that the order of pushing the halfs on the stack is shown by the arrows
3
2
1
```

pop the stack back : `5 6 7 8 4 3 2 1`

Continue dividing the halfs:

iter=2  `<-56` `->78` `<-43` `->21`; odd halfs `56`,`43`; even halfs `78`,`21`

start from the end and fill the stack; inter is even so start with the first even halfs

```
5 
6
4 
3
8 <-even halfs end, odd halfs start 
7
1 
2
```

Pop the stack back: `5 6 4 3 8 7 1 2`

Divide the segments again, since there will be only one element in each new half the arrows are used just to highlight the rule:

iter=3 `->5` `<-6` `->4` `<-3` `->8` `<-7` `->1` `<-2`

iter is odd, so fill the stack odd halfs first

```
 6
 3
 7
 2 
 5
 4
 8 
 1
```

Pop the stack back, and you are done: `63725481`

I hope this makes sense; happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a law, the element in array whose index is `(2*n-1, 2*n)`, the `n` is odd, always array before the rest elements whatever direction your folded. For example, the array `12345678`, the elements `2367` always are front of the `1458`. Now I have used `dichotomy` for getting two arrays.  Next you maybe find the law in two arrays. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your interviewer expected something like:

```
private int[] Fold(int pow)
   {
      if (pow < 0)
        throw new Exception("illegal input");

      int n = 1;
      for (int factor = 1; factor <= pow; factor++)
        n *= 2;

      Stack<int> storage = new Stack<int>(n);

      this.Add(n, 1, storage);

      int[] result = new int[n];
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        result[k] = storage.Pop();

      return result;
    }

    private void Add(int n, int value, Stack<int> storage)
    {
      storage.Push(value);

      int m = n;
      while (true)
      {
        int mirror = m + 1 - value;
        if (mirror <= value)
          break;
        this.Add(n, mirror, storage);
        m /= 2;
      }
    }
```

{ demonstrating that you know about stacks AND about recursion ;-) }

Comment: Thanks for the note; sorry about the language (didn't pay attention to that part of the specs), guess the interviewee will be able to reformulate it in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution turned iterative; hence a stack, although probably not as intended. The function returns the starting position of an element based on the given position. It seems to be of time `O(1/2n(log n + 1))` and space `O(log n)`.

JavaScript Code:

```js
function f(n,y,x,l){
  var stack = [[n,y,x,l]];
  while (stack[0]){
    var temp = stack.pop();
    var n = temp[0], y = temp[1], x = temp[2], l = temp[3];
    var m = 1 << l;
    if (m == 1)
      return x;
    if (l % 2 == 0){
      if (y > m / 2)
        stack.push([n * 2,y - m / 2,n + n - x + 1,l - 1]);
      else
        stack.push([n * 2,y,x,l - 1]);
    } else if (y > m / 2){
      stack.push([n * 2,y - m / 2,n - x + 1,l - 1]);
    } else
      stack.push([n * 2,y,x + n,l - 1]);
  }
}

function g(p){
  var n = 1 << p;
  for (var i=1; i<n; i+=2){
    var a = f(1,i,1,p);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(n - a + 1);
  }
}

g(3)
```